# Shape moves out of the window area

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want my shape not to go out of the window area. for example when I press the left button the shape moves out of the window area but I want it to hit the side and stay there.

```
 def update

    if button_down?(Gosu::KbRight)
      if @shape_x != (WIDTH - SHAPE_DIM)
        @shape_x += 3
      end
    end
    if button_down?(Gosu::KbLeft) 
      if @shape_x != (WIDTH - SHAPE_DIM)
        @shape_x -= 3
      end
    end
    if button_down?(Gosu::KbUp) 
      @shape_y -= 3
  end
  if button_down?(Gosu::KbDown) 
    @shape_y += 3
end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WIDTH is Window width, you must use `<` and `>`, instead of `!=`

```
  def update

    if button_down?(Gosu::KbRight)
      if @shape_x < (WIDTH - SHAPE_DIM)
        @shape_x += 3
      end
    end
    if button_down?(Gosu::KbLeft) 
      if @shape_x > (WIDTH - SHAPE_DIM)
        @shape_x -= 3
      end
    end
    if button_down?(Gosu::KbUp) 
      @shape_y -= 3
    end
    if button_down?(Gosu::KbDown) 
      @shape_y += 3
    end

  end
```